# Redirect from related list flow button

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created Custom button on my related list to run flow on selected "ids", how can I redirect user back to Account record?
I was even trying to use custom solution like "Navigate everywhere" from unofficial SF but it doesn't work

it's simlpe list button:
/flow/Supply_Network_Set

Adding returl doesn't work, fetching AccountId and redirect using custom component doesn't work.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Please use [edit] and show both paths you took (actual code/flow config)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Custom Buttons are very old technology and they use an old version of the Flow runtime that doesn't handle redirect events. That's why Navigate Everywhere doesn't work.

I would attack this problem by replacing the related list with a screen flow that includes a Data Table. The user would be able to select rows and click Next and at the end, Navigate Everywhere would work because Screen Flows use the modern Flow runtime.